# SOLIDITY: Some issue when trying to swamp ERC20 to ERC20 on testnetbsc

Tags: solidity, remix, erc20

I'm getting some issue when trying to swamp a fakeBUSD (ERC20 token) to another one ERC20 that the contract have.

I'm having some trouble with allowance/approve, but I think to have done all correct trying/understanding the solution on others stackoverflow post.

Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

```
pragma solidity 0.7.5;

import "./SafeERC20.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

contract BusdtoRahi is Ownable {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    IERC20 public BUSD; 
    IERC20 public RAHI;

    uint256 public price = 2 * 1e18; // 2 BUSD per RAHItoken

    bool public started; // true when sale is started

    bool public ended; // true when sale is ended

    bool public contractPaused; // circuit breaker


    event Deposit(address indexed who, uint256 amount);
    event SaleStarted(uint256 block);
    event SaleEnded(uint256 block);
    event AdminWithdrawal(address token, uint256 amount);

    constructor(
        address _RAHI,
        address _BUSD
    ) {
        require( _RAHI != address(0) );
        RAHI = IERC20(_RAHI);
        require( _BUSD != address(0) );
        BUSD = IERC20(_BUSD);
    }
    modifier checkIfPaused() {
        require(contractPaused == false, "contract is paused");
        _;
    }

    function setPrice(uint256 _price) external onlyOwner {
        require(!started, "Sale has already started");
        price = _price * 1e18;
    }

    function start() external onlyOwner {
        require(!started, "Sale has already started");
        started = true;
        emit SaleStarted(block.number);
    }

    function end() external onlyOwner {
        require(started, "Sale has not started");
        require(!ended, "Sale has already ended");
        ended = true;
        emit SaleEnded(block.number);
    }

    function togglePause() external onlyOwner returns (bool){
        contractPaused = !contractPaused;
        return contractPaused;
    }

    function adminWithdraw(address _token, uint256 _amount) external onlyOwner {
        IERC20( _token ).safeTransfer( address(msg.sender), _amount );
        emit AdminWithdrawal(_token, _amount);
    }

    function deposit(uint256 _amount) external checkIfPaused {
        require(started, 'Sale has not started');
        require(!ended, 'Sale has ended');
   
        uint256 payout = _amount.mul(1e18).div(price).div(1e9); 

        BUSD.approve(address(this), _amount);
        BUSD.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        BUSD.safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        
        RAHI.approve(msg.sender, payout);
        RAHI.allowance(address(this), msg.sender);
        RAHI.safeTransferFrom(address(this),msg.sender, payout);

        emit Deposit(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
    



}
```

This is the code, the problem is that Metamask is not getting (using remix ide) the busd that I deposit with function deposit(), so nothing come back (the "rahi token").

Thanks!

Comment: when you call `BUSD.approve(address(this),_amount)` the contract is the msgs.sender of the approve function, so the contract is approving to some address to move the tokens, but you are approving the contract to move their own tokens, I imagine that you want to make the user approve your contract to move the BUSD, if that is the case you can't do it in the contract, the approve should be done in the frontend that interacts with the contract, or the user directly interacts with the BUSD contract

Comment: @jhonny Hey! Thanks for reply. Pratically yes, i want to move BUSD from a customer to my contract and change it with token that the smart contract own. So pratically a swamp TOKEN-ERC20/TOKEN-ERC20.

So i have to delete all the allowance/approve functions from the smart contract, and use it on the "dapp", correct? Thanks!

Comment: yes that's correct